# What is wrong with my succulent?

Tags: succulents

[image]

i’ve just bought this Pachyphytum Oviferum. I noticed spots where the coating on it was missing but I just assumed it was wiped of. Now I’’m worried it could be something else that caused it since there are also these white patches appearing in places where the coating/farina is missing. What could be causing this?

Comment: The big "leaf" at the top looks llke it has a dirty finger print on it! Some of the other marks could be splashes from careless watering. If the marks get worse over time for no reason, you might try propagating some new plants from the healthiest looking parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coating is like a powdered wax that the plant produces to protect the skin and attenuate water loss, the cuticle. It's not terrible when some is wiped off, but it looks unsightly. It will probably fill back in very slowly over time.

I wouldn't be concerned by what I see. It should sort itself out eventually.

I tried to find a reference, but time is short.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping it would fill back at some point...what about the white patches ? Could that be from powdery mildew or something?

Comment: I'm not sure. It looks like where the cuticle was pushed into piles. I'm guessing if you touched one of those spots gently it would wipe off.